# The total number of logs collected by Loki

Tags: grafana-loki

I'm new to Loki. I want to find information about the total number of logs collected by Loki. To figure out, I've integrated Loki's Prometheus metrics with Prometheus and then, I looked through all collected metrics. But I can't find a metric related to the total number of collected logs.

I found two metrics(`loki_log_messages_total`, `loki_internal_log_messages_total`) which look like the total number of logs, but these were the total number of internal logs not "total logs".

I checked [Loki's observability](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/observability/) document, but I can't find a proper metric on the doc, too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. `loki_log_messages_total` and `loki_internal_log_messages_total` are metrics of loki itself.
If you want to query the total number of collected logs, you can use the logQL function `count_over_time(log-range)` in loki.